# Reference "to any" with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, reference

is it possible to model a reference to "any" (entity) with JPA? Similar to a reference of type Object in Java, which can hold any object.

Thanks for your answer,

Dominik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think about representation of the reference in database.

- If reference is represented by a single foreign key, then referenced column should be guaranteed to be unique for all possible referenced entities. In JPA it's possible only for entites in inheritance hierarchy, so you'll get a reference to the root of some inheretence hierarchy of entites instead of `Object`.
- Reference may be represented by a pair of values <type of referenced entity, foreign key>. This case is not supported by plain JPA, but supported in Hibernate by Hibernate's own [`@Any` annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-any).

Comment: Is it possible to extend JPA with a custom reference resolver, which would do more or less the same as Hibernate's @Any? I don't think it would be a good idea to mix JPA and Hibernate entities, wouldn't it?

Comment: @raymi: There is not need to do it, Hibernate annotations work fine with JPA.

Answer (score 0):

According to DataNucleus this is not possible (search in this for java.lang.Object):
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/jpa/types.html

For JDO we introduced our our Object-like abstract class called Subject which is annotated for persistence and extended all other persistable object from it.  That works in JDO and I think it should work in JPA as well.